# How do I access files on my Windows 7 PC from my Galaxy 5S cell phone?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-access-point

I have an HP Pavillion with AMD dual processor 3.20Ghz with 16GB of DDR3 memory using windows 7 professional.

I want to access files(music-media player, videos, etc) thaT ARE ON MY pc from my Galaxy 5s cell phone.

I would like to do this from home wirelessly or away from home.

How can I achieve this?

Please Im very good at computers but was reading about servers and confusing stuff. Can you help me please?

Comment: [Maybe this answer](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1665632/connecting-android-device-windows-homegroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method **I know** is to create a share for the individual Folders on your computer (you have to have the sharing option of files and printers in your network settings enabled). I did it the following way:

1. Select your folder which you want to share - right click - Share with - Home group

For a more complete instruction you can go [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-share-folders-without-homegroups-in-windows-7-3434911/).

2. Use a file explorer on your phone ( I like ES File Explorer ), swipe right, select Network - LAN and select your computer.
3. Enter the login information to your pc user account and you should be good to go.

Note that this solution works just for the intranet as far as I know.